# How to select all options in select2 JavaScript multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

The other day, I was trying to figure out how to select all items in select2 v3.5.1 JavaScript multiselect control. I tried a few things, but I was having a difficult time figuring out how to do it. I just wanted to select every option in the box, but apparently select2 does not have a built-in option to select all of the items for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slightly more efficient version of the OP's answer:

```
var selectedItems = [];
var allOptions = $("#IncludeFieldsMulti option");
allOptions.each(function() {
    selectedItems.push( $(this).val() );
});
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").select2("val", selectedItems);
```

Or to make it more concise:

```
var selectedItems = $('#IncludeFieldsMulti option').map(function() { return this.value });
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").select2("val", selectedItems);
```

Answer (score 9):

For select2 4.0.0

```
var selectedItems = [];
var allOptions = $("#IncludeFieldsMulti option");
allOptions.each(function() {
    selectedItems.push( $(this).val() );
});
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").val(selectedItems).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the discussion here: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/195 it is possible to add a `Select All` button inside the dropdown list of options. Per that discussion, selecting too many at once can freeze the browser. Here I have added a functionality to disable the `select all` button if there are more that 25 options listed:

https://jsfiddle.net/hula_zell/50v60cm6/

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I would like to use this with version 4.1 but it does not work. Do you have any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/mbejLx17/

Comment: The problem on 4.1.0 is the way you will get the data attribute.
on 4.1.0 is 
    var data = Utils.GetData(this, 'data'); 
instead of 
    var data = $result.data('data');

Comment: Works nicely for me

Answer (score 0):

To Select ALL

```
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").select2("destroy");
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").find('option').attr('selected',true);
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").select2();
```

To Unselect ALL

```
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").select2("destroy");
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").find('option').attr('selected',false);
$("#IncludeFieldsMulti").select2();
```