# How to set all options of a select as value for "All" options option?

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have an app using jquery select2 plugin for select-option filters. Is there a solution to have an option called "All", which selects all available option values and passes them for the result for the select? Like append all options to one option in array or something and displaying it as first option. How and where to add it on the select2() function? I am interested in a solution that will prepend to all options like so:

```
<option value="LIST OF ALL OPTIONS SEPARATED BY COMMA HERE">All</option>
```

So I could get a result like this below:

```
<option value="US,UK,DE...">All</option> // like this but not sure how to grab all the values and prepend this here.
<option value="US">United States</option>
<option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="DE">Germany</option>
...
```

I've been searching and I can't find what I need. My select2 instance does not use multiple choices select. As far as I understand it to display all options I need all values separated with comma in the value attribute of the option tag.

For example there is an option for selecting a country. And some results are for all countries. How do I select all options with select2? Any advice appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Select2 - How to select all options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538399/jquery-select2-how-to-select-all-options)

Comment: Also see [How to select all options in select2 JavaScript multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244335/how-to-select-all-options-in-select2-javascript-multiselect).

Comment: Thanks for your replies but not really. I would need a solution that will prepend option called All in the text of option list but in the option value to have all the options separated by comma, so that when "All" is selected, filter returns results for all available options.

Comment: May you explain further why you need this? If you want to process it in the back-end with this information, more easily would be to just put some other value like "all" or "-1", then in back-end check if this value is selected and if it is, replace it with all the values you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to:

1. Get all values from `<select>`, separated by commas.
2. Prepend an `<option>` with the new value, called "ALL".

```js
$('.makeAll').each(function() {

  $select = $(this);

  var values = $('option', $select).map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).toArray().join(',');

  $('<option>', {
    'value': values,
    'text': 'ALL'
  }).prependTo($select);

});

// For demo; output the selected value.
$('select').on('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="makeAll">
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
</select>

<select class="makeAll">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

---

### EDIT

Note that values with commas will be considered multiple values, because the delimiters are the same. For example:

```
<option value="1,2,3,4">
```

I used a variable for the delimiter so it can be easily changed as needed:

```js
var delim = '#';

$('.makeAll').each(function() {

  var $select = $(this);

  var values = $('option', $select).map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).toArray().join(delim);

  $('<option>', {
    'value': values,
    'text': 'ALL'
  }).prependTo($select);

});

// For demo; output the selected value(s).
$('select').on('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value.split(delim));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="makeAll">
  <option value="1,2,3,4">Sample</option>
  <option value="spin">Funnel</option>
  <option value="4,22(n,s)">Igloo</option>
</select>

<select class="makeAll">
  <option value="1-2-3-4">Result</option>
  <option value="spin;watch">Crystal</option>
  <option value="4,22(n-s)">Curtain</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement on my instance.

Comment: That works well. The problem is I use select2 plugin and it removes the styling and the All option is not present when select2 is enabled for the select parent element. Maybe I have to seek other ways.

Comment: Found another solution. Checked if response is >=2 and for the select2 used placeholder and allowClear:true. Also prepended option with value attribute set to "". This way there is an X to clear the selected option and it shows all by default.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I'd initialize select2 after generating the ALL options. I haven't see the rest of your setup or your final code, but it sounds promising.

Comment: select2 is on $( document ).ready() but thanks for your suggestion. I could try that. And yes, that's why I wanted all the values comma separated. But also empty value in my case returns all results. I just noticed. Maybe it is because of the queries I do. I will test it a bit more and let know, if I meet difficulties. The instance is very complex to reproduce here. Once again - thank you!!